# Airflow:Push XCOM from SQL File

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to push to xcom from the SQL file?

I have a SnowflakeOperator which executes the SQL file and I would like to pass the row count to the xcom

```sql
select count(*) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the results of the query, you can use the Snowflake hook with PythonOperator. Something along these lines:

```
def row_count(**kwargs):
    dwh_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn")
    result = dwh_hook.get_first("select count(*) table")
    return result

get_count = PythonOperator(task_id="get_count", python_callable=row_count)
```

[source](https://itnext.io/connect-apache-airflow-to-snowflake-data-warehouse-37936a9edfa1)

The return value of `python_callable` is automatically pushed to XCOM.

You can check out [the code of the hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.html) for more interesting functions.